# JNI calls from C++ to Java and vice versa

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I hava a C++ process whose job is to call the `main` method of one of my Java classes using the JNI.  This C++ process has a shared object say `libabc.so`.

My Java process is getting invoked, doing its intended job.

Now I want to call C++ native functions existing in `libabc.so`.

I have 2 questions on this:

1. Whether in java code is there a need to do `System.load("abc")`, since my java class has in fact been called from the C++ process
2. If I don't use it I am not able to call C++ functions, though I don't get an error
3. If I do that my load fails with a call to `std::terminate`, stating that some libraries were already loaded.

Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your C++ functions in the libabc.so library formatted to be called from Java? i.e. generated prototypes via javah

Comment: Yes they are genrated via javah ...Infact if i create a different so with somefunctions , generate signatures via javah for that functions , load that using Sytem.looad (or System.loadLibrary) it works and I am able to call native functions

Comment: You will need to call System.load("abc"), or Java won't think the library is loaded.  Since you want the same library directly accessible from your C++ process as well, you should try letting Java load the library via System.load, and then have your C++ process load it via dlopen